# Use of Clock triggers ask for "Publish as web app" permission

Tags: google-apps-script

I just added a use of Clock Triggers to Add-on, by using ScriptApp service, and besides the ask for permission to:

**"Allow this application to run when you are not present"**

it also asked the permission to:

**"Publish this application as a web app or a service that may share your data"**

This doesn't make sense for Add-ons and is scary for the end user, creating an additional barrier for the Add-on installation.

Are there any way to avoid asking this permission, when using clock triggers on an Add-on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4354) with automatic scope detection where scopes are requested if the service name and method name appear anywhere within the same script. For example if `ScriptApp` and `getService()` appear within the same script, even in comments, the scope for `ScriptApp.getService()` will be requested. Please check your code to see if this is the case, and try to rename functions to eliminate these unnecessary scopes.

Comment: In our case, the we had a function named `enable()`, as well as the ScriptApp usage. Renaming the function to `enableTrigger()` solved the Issue. Thanks Eric!